# Azure rewrite rules causing error 404 in detailed logs

Tags: node.js, azure, restify

I have a website with the following structure at the root for a Node.js app

```
package.json
server.js
public
    index.html
    css
    js
    images
...other folders
```

I would like to take the person only inside the public folder with a forced HTTPS connection.

My current web.config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>

         <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>    

        <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^zupbot\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.zup.chat/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>


      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Whenever I try to access my website, it tries finding a server.js and gives me this error
{"code":"NotAuthorized","message":"/server.js"}

My node.js code does this to serve static files

```
server.get('/.*/', restify.serveStatic({

    //Ensure that people can only access the files within the public directory and none of the protected server files
    directory: __dirname + '/public',
    default: constants.INDEX_HTML,
    match: /^((?!server.js).)*$/   // we should deny access to the application source
}));
```

How can I take the person straight inside the public folder always with an HTTPS connection? Thank you for your help in advance.

UPDATE 1

I added the HTTPS redirect before any other rule that has a stopProcessing=true and it works , however if I go to my native site http://.azurewebsites.net, it still takes me to the https version of it, how can I redirect sitename.azurewebsites.net to the https version of my custom domain?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following rewrite rules in `web.config`:

```
<rule name="DynamicContent" stopProcessing="true">
     <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Which will rewrite the url `your_site.azurewebsites.net/<asset>` to `https` protocol if there is a file named `<asset>` in public folder as you configured in `restify.serveStatic`.

And it will not rewrite the url those can match the route setting in your restify application.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.